# Approximate Pi/Taylor series; prompt user input

Tags: c, user-input, pi, taylor-series

I have another problem for homework. This time I know where I am at generally, but I can see that I have some glaring issues with the code. Recently I lost my keys, and it's kind of like that. I don't know exactly WHERE I went wrong with my code, but I have a good idea, and I'd like you to help me find it.

The problem is to approximate pi using the Taylor series. 
Now, my problem isn't exactly to get it to approxate so that it equals pi. Rather approximate pi **using first N terms** *as entered* by the user. So for example, if I would enter 2, then I should run through the first 2 since N=2. My problem is the way printF represents it (and a variable appears to be uninitialized). Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{ 
   //program to calculate series of numbers equal to pi/4

   //declare variables

   int num_Terms;
   int sign= 1;
   int n;
   float sum= 0.0;
   float next_Term;
   float final_sum;

   //prompt user for input

   printf("Enter a value for integer n:  ");
   scanf("%i",&n);

   //perform calculations

   for(n = 1; n<= num_Terms; n=n+1) {
      sum= sum+next_Term;
      next_Term = sign*(1.0/(2*n-1));
      sign = sign*-1;
   }
   final_sum = sum*4;

   //display result
   printf("\n 4 * %f = %f\n",sum, final_sum);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%i",&num_Terms);`  `sign = -sign;`

Comment: Not to be rude, but that just kind of creates more problems. I'm sorry.

Comment: I agree with negative sign though.

Comment: It turns the previous uninitialized warning into an error.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know exactly WHERE I went wrong with my code

Firstly you are scanning value into a variable *n* and then later using it as an iterator variable. Change this to be *num_Terms*. This should solve your main problem of not considering the number of terms.

Then, it is preferable to initialize the variable before you use it, which would then get rid of the warning you get.

```
int main(void)
{ 
   //program to calculate series of numbers equal to pi/4

   //declare variables

   int   num_Terms = 0;
   int   sign      = 1;
   int   n         = 0;
   float sum       = 0;
   float next_Term = 0;
   float final_sum = 0;

   //prompt user for input

   printf("Enter a value for integer n:  ");
   scanf("%i",&num_Terms);

   //perform calculations

   for(n = 1; n<= num_Terms; n=n+1) {
     //not too sure if you need to reverse this order of calculation of sum
      sum = sum + next_Term;
      next_Term = sign * (1.0/(2*n-1));
      sign = sign * -1;
   }
   final_sum = sum * 4;

   //display result
   printf("\n 4 * %f = %f\n",sum, final_sum);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: thought it would be something like that. something simple. thank you.